# draw table after ajax does not apply to filtration

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables, filtering

I'm having a datatable with buttons work using ajax to update some data in the table. This table has a filtration drop down menu. [jsfiddle without ajax but the same issue](https://jsfiddle.net/fce3tved/)

```
var table = $('#data').DataTable({
  "lengthMenu": [[50, 100, -1], [50, 100, "All"]]
});

<tr><td>jack</td><td>2016</td><td>paid</td></tr>
<tr><td>andy</td><td>2015</td><td>didn't pay<input type="button" id="1" class="btn"></td></tr>
```

and drop down menu with 2 values: paid and didn't pay

clicking the button changes the text to "paid" no problem at all. After success:

```
$("#status").change(function() {    
table.column(2).search($(this).val()).draw() });
 $(".btn").on('click',function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $.post('ajax/pay.php',{id:id}).done(function (data) {
            if(data.trim().indexOf('ok')>-1){
                alert('done'); //alert is displayed
                $(".btn[id="+id+"]").fadeOut('normal'); //faded out
                $(".btn[id="+id+"]").parent().text('paid'); //text changed
                table.draw();
            }                  
        });
    });
```

but when I change the drop down menu to "paid" i can't see the second row and when I change to "didn't pay' I can see it which means the drop down menu didn't recognize the change that happened after the AJAX.
So is there any way to make the filtration parameters reload or redraw the table after the AJAX to display updated data?
Thanks in advance and best wishes.

Answer (score 1):

You need change the data in your DataTable, you're just change the text, you can use [cell().data()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/cell().data()).

**First,** get the tr element:

```
var oTr = $(this).closest('tr');
```

**Second,** get row of table:

```
var row = table.row(oTr);
```

And **finally**, change the data and draw the table (Remember indicate the index of column, in this case is 2):

```
table.cell(row, 2).data("paid").draw();
```

Your code should look like:

```
$(".btn").on('click',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    alert('done'); 
    $(".btn[id="+id+"]").fadeOut('normal'); 
    //$(".btn[id="+id+"]").parent().text('paid'); 
    var oTr = $(this).closest('tr');

    var row = table.row(oTr);
    table.cell(row, 2).data("paid").draw();

});
```

**Result:** https://jsfiddle.net/fce3tved/1/

**UPDATE CODE:**

```
$(".btn").on('click',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $.post('ajax/pay.php',{id:id}).done(function (data) {
        if(data.trim().indexOf('ok')>-1){
            alert('done'); //alert is displayed
            $(".btn[id="+id+"]").fadeOut('normal'); //faded out
            //$(".btn[id="+id+"]").parent().text('paid'); //text changed
            //table.draw();
            var oTr = $(this).closest('tr');
            var row = table.row(oTr);
            table.cell(row, 2).data("paid").draw();
        }                  
    });
});
```

Comment: with the AJAX call the .data doesn't change cell content while .text changes the text but .draw is still not working: 
    $(".btn.paySt[id="+id+"]").closest('tr').children("td:eq(5)").data("paid");